# Logarithmic axis with modified ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, axis, r-plotly

I'm trying to re-create the below graph but am not able to get rid of the 'half-step' increments for x > 3. Is there a better way of doing this? I'm using `ggplot2` for now - to get it right and then plan on switching to `plotly` for interactive plots.

**Code**

Only showing 3 traces for PoC:

```
set.seed(69)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

k <- lapply(1:10, function(z){
  ret <- sample(x = (5*z):100, 
                size = 20, 
                replace = T)
  dat <- data.table(V1 =  ret[order(ret)] )
  colnames(dat) <- paste('trace', z, sep = '')
  return(dat)
  })

dat <- do.call(cbind, k)
dat$size <- c(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), 2:11)

ggplot(dat[size >= 0.2, ], aes(x = size)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.5, aes(y = trace1), color = '#003366') + 
  geom_line(size = 1.5, aes(y = trace2), 
            color = rgb(red = 0, green = 103, blue = 62, maxColorValue = 255)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.5, aes(y = trace3), color = '#b20000') + 
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), 2:11))
```

**Output**

[image]

**Desired Plot**

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'half step increments', could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @teunbrand the graph I want to recreate does not have any 'breaks' on the x-axis between 2 and 3 or 4 and 5 whereas they do exist in the one I made. I also want to not show the x-axis label for 3,5,7 etc. while still showing the corresponding grid marks.

Comment: You asked for 3, 5, 7, etc. in your  `scale_x_log10(breaks = c(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), 2:11))` call.  Print `c(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), 2:11)` and you'll see the requested breaks.  Change that vector to the breaks you want.  Use `minor_breaks` where you don't want numerical labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to start with `ggplot2`. You can do this directly in `plotly`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(plotly)

dat %>% 
  filter(size >= 0.2) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-size) %>% 
 plot_ly(x = ~size, y = ~value, color = ~name, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(type = "log",
                      tickvals = as.list(c(seq(0.2,1,0.2), seq(2,10,2)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was using ggplot2 because the computer where this needs to be done has issues installing plotly and orca (for exporting to pdf or svg) :)

Comment: @Gautam Sure. Just one thing to take out of my answer; you can convert your data from wide to long so you can have one `geom_line` instead of multiple ones for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Minor grid lines can be removed via the theme, by setting `panel.grid.minor = element_blank()`.

```r
set.seed(69)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

k <- lapply(1:10, function(z){
  ret <- sample(x = (5*z):100, 
                size = 20, 
                replace = T)
  dat <- data.table(V1 =  ret[order(ret)] )
  colnames(dat) <- paste('trace', z, sep = '')
  return(dat)
})

dat <- do.call(cbind, k)
dat$size <- c(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), 2:11)

ggplot(dat[size >= 0.2, ], aes(x = size)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.5, aes(y = trace1), color = '#003366') + 
  geom_line(size = 1.5, aes(y = trace2), 
            color = rgb(red = 0, green = 103, blue = 62, maxColorValue = 255)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.5, aes(y = trace3), color = '#b20000') + 
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), 2:11)) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>